# UICollectionViewLayout prepareLayout is called for any scrolling

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Found this strange behavior while implementing a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass. I set up the subclass methods except for `collectionViewContentSize`. All the cells showed up where I expected, but the `contentView` was too long. Looked to be about double what it should be.

I implemented the method below to get the correct `contentSize`. Though, it's now the expected value, `prepareLayout` is called every single time the view scrolls one pixel. That means if I swipe from 0,0 to 0,500, `prepareLayout` is called 500 times!

What is it about my `collectionViewContentSize` that could cause that?

```
- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *leftAttributes = (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)self.layoutInfo[@"segmentCell"][[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0]-1 inSection:0]];
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *rightAttributes = (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)self.layoutInfo[@"segmentCell"][[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:1]-1 inSection:1]];
    float leftHeight = leftAttributes.frame.size.height + leftAttributes.frame.origin.y;
    float rightHeight = rightAttributes.frame.size.height + rightAttributes.frame.origin.y;
    float maxHeight = leftHeight > rightHeight ? leftHeight : rightHeight;
    return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width, maxHeight);
}
```

Comment: Are you implementing __shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:__ by __YES__ returning?

Comment: No, I did not implement that yet.

Comment: If your custom layout is a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass, if you set an `estimatedItemSize` then `prepare()` will be called on scrolling if a cell is appearing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although according to the docs [0] `shoulInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:` is supposed to return NO by default, it wasn't. Once I implemented it and had it return NO in all cases, `prepareLayout` is no longer called with every bounds change. That seems like a bug in UICollectionViewLayout.

[0] http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

A reason why you would want this to happen is that when using a custom layout, you may want the size of the cell to change depending on the content offset such as when you swipe up on an iPhone X where the Y value determines the size of the cell. This saves you from having to deal with separate gesture recognisers for a particular effect you might want.